# is this a valid xpath and if so what does it mean?

Tags: xpath

/html/body/input[@id='query' and @name='query' and @value='Search Text']

Comment: I agree with the answers below. Just one small consideration: this xpath would most likely not find any results in a real HTML document, because `<input>` elements should be contained within `<form>` elements.

Comment: Try ...`/body//input/`... The double `//` means "search the whole tree below for"

Comment: damn, i knew before i enter here that the xpath will be trivial :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's valid.

It points to this element (or elements, if it's more than one of them);

```
<html>
    <body>
        <input id="query" name="query" value="Search Text" />
...
```

Answer (score 1):

yes, its valid. It means your selecting the node input which has the attribute id as query, name as query and value as search text

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is this will get all the `input`'s that have a direct parent of `body` which in turn has a direct parent `html` where `html` has to be the root element. Further more the selected `input`'s must have an `id` attribute with the value `query` AND a `name` attribute with the value `query` AND a `value` attribute with the value `Search Text`.

Answer (score 1):

all the input elements, within a body element within a html element, with attribute id='query' and attribute name='query' and attribute value='Search Text'.